# What kind of values can the HTML5 itemid attribute have?

Tags: html

I was wondering what kind of values can the itemid attribute have beacuse I see it with a url value for example `http://purl.oreilly.com/products/9780596007683.BOOK` and with a set of numbers like a Books ISBN# for example, `urn:isbn:0-330-34032-8` so what is the official value for the itemid attribute in laymans terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be [a valid URL](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/2009-10-27/multipage/microdata.html#attr-itemid).